# Finding point of inequality in two arrays

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a program that returns the index of the first point of inequality between two lists in Python. The code I've written is

```py
a0: List[int] = [1, 2]
a1: List[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a2: List[int] = [1, 2, 33, 4, 5]

def diff_index(l1:list, l2: list):
    if len(l1) < len(l2):
        smallest = len(l1)
    else:
        smallest = len(l2)
    i = 0
    j = -1
    while i < smallest:
        if l1[i] != l2[i]:
            j = i
            break
        else:
            i += 1
    return j
```

Which doesn't work for the lists above. I cannot understand what's wrong with my code, since it doesn't return anything.

Comment: tried on colab and `diff_index(a0,a1)` gave me -1. What do you mean by `doesn't return anything` ?

Comment: Please make an example along expected result for better specification.

Comment: you need to handle case when len of both list are same

Answer (score 1):

Your code is partially working, a good platform for you to debug is
https://pythontutor.com/ - if you run it you can see what's happening in each step and learn to debug yourself. I think it's a super important skill while learning a new language.

Alternatively you could this `zip_longest` with **enumerate** to achieve your goal of *finding the first index of difference*:

[Note] this is similar with earlier post, but *fix the syntax* problem as you can see.

```
def diff_index(lst1, lst2):
    for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip_longest(lst1, lst2)):
        if a != b:     # find the difference
           return idx
    return -1          # not found difference
```

Running:

```
diff_index(a0, a1)     # 2
diff_index(a1, a2)     # 2
diff_index(a1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # -1   <- no difference
```